# R Wald test for cluster robust se's

Tags: r

I would like to **test for the significance of my model**. I have read that because I am using a **cluster-robust model** the F-test doesn't hold and instead I should use a **Wald test**.

My script currently looks like this and all of these different options give me corrected cluster-robust se's:

**Option 1:**

```
m <- lm(y_var ~ var1 + poly(var2, 2) + quartier, data = df)

m_robust_clustered <- coeftest(m, vcov = vcovCL,
                                    type = "HC1",
                                    df = 9,  # There are 10 quartiers, so 10-1 = 9
                                    cluster = ~ quartier) # retrieve cluster robust se's
```

**Option 2: (using miceadds)**

```
m <- lm.cluster(y_var ~ var1 + poly(var2, 2) + quartier,
                     cluster = 'quartier',
                     data = df)
```

**Option 3: (using estimatr)**

```
m <- lm_robust(y_var ~ var1 + poly(var2, 2) + quartier, cluster = quartier, data = df)
```

My issue is that from here I cannot figure out how to perform a Wald test. I have looked at both waldtest() and Wald_test() functions but none of these work:

```
waldtest(m)

Wald_test(m)
```

**==> What am I missing here ? Which syntax should I be using for the wald test in each of the regression coding above ?**

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I would also very much like an answer to this! Did you find a solution @mimi ?

Comment: @milsandhills I've provided an answer with one way to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

The details of functions with names like "Wald test" can differ among packages. Some are designed for testing nested models, and wouldn't work for single models as shown in the question (which doesn't seem to specify which packages provided these `waldtest()` or `Wald_test()` functions).

A safe (if not the easiest to use) choice would be the `wald.test()` function in the R [`aod` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=aod). Usage is:

```
wald.test(Sigma, b, Terms = NULL, L = NULL, H0 = NULL, df = NULL, verbose = FALSE)
```

where `Sigma` is the variance-covariance matrix from the model, `b` is the vector of model coefficients, and you choose between `Terms` and `L` to specify what to test. It doesn't accept a model; you specify the coefficient vector and the variance-covariance matrix directly. Use `Terms` for a joint test on a set of coefficients; use `L` to test linear combinations of coefficients. The default null hypothesis `H0` is all equal to 0. For the overall model Wald test, you would specify `Terms` as an integer vector specifying all of the coefficients, for example `1:length(coef(model))` if `coef(model)` returns a vector.