# Compare regression with robust standard errors to null using Wald's Test in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, robust

I am running a regression model that looks like this:

```
wwMLR <- lm(contAOMIdiff ~ PHQ9 + KVIQtot, data = wwMeanWide4)
```

Having used `check_heteroscedasticity(wwMLR)` from the Performance package I can see that the regression model violates the assumption of homoscedasticity. Due to this I have built a model with robust standard errors shown below:

```
library(estimatr)  
wwMLR_hc3 <- lm_robust(formula = contAOMIdiff ~ PHQ9 + KVIQtot, data = wwMeanWide4, 
          se_type = "HC3", alpha = 0.0482)
```

What I would like to do now is compare this regression model to a null using Wald's Test. The null model looks like the below:

```
wwnull_hc3 <- lm_robust(formula = contAOMIdiff ~ 1, data = wwMeanWide4, 
                       se_type = "HC3", alpha = 0.0482)
```

When I try to compare these using a Wald's Test:

```
library(lmtest)
waldtest(wwMLR_hc3, wwnull_hc3, vcov = vcovHC)
```

I get an error:

```
Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'contAOMIdiff' not found
```

`contAOMIdiff` is my response variable in the regression. I am not sure why it can't be found but I am assuming this may be a compatibility issue between the `lm_robust` model type and the `waldtest()` function.

If anyone has any ideas on how I can get this to work, or an alternate way to run a Wald's Test on these two models I would be very grateful.

I have found a similar question here, which has not been answered: [R Wald test for cluster robust se's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69940348/r-wald-test-for-cluster-robust-ses)

Comment: From what pkg is the 'waldtest' function that you're using? Does it have a 'data' argument, such that you could add `data = wwMeanWide4`?

Comment: @AMBarbosa ah, sorry, I should have specified! The waldtest() function is from the lmtest package. Adding the data argument gives me a new error:
"Error in modelUpdate(objects[[i - 1]], objects[[i]]) : 
  original model was of class "lm_robust", updated model is of class "grouped_df""